# Variable floating oddly

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with an unordered list when I insert a variable inside an image.
Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1awq15w/4/).

So basically, what I get here is a list of images, centred and floated to the left, with left alignment on new lines as well.
In Jsfiddle I used a random image. When I copy this code exactly as it is into my code it works fine. When I swap the random image to a PHP variable the whole list jumps around and it looks very bad. Allow me to illustrate what I see with a PHP variable inserted:

[image]

I have no idea why this becomes like this. Here is my code with the PHP variable:

```
<div class="snaps-wrap">
                <ul>
                     <?php 
                   //Here is php code which works fine
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img id="snap-img" src="<?php echo $snappic?>" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                     <?php }
                    } 
                   ?>
                <p style="clear: both;"></p>    
                </ul>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.snaps-wrap {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}
.snaps-wrap ul {
   padding: 0.5em 0; 
   text-align:center; 
   margin:0 auto; 
   background:#ddd; 
   list-style: none;;
}
.snaps-wrap ul li {
  float: left; 
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0.5em 0;

}
#snap-img {
width: 150px;
}
```

As I mentioned, with the image used in jsfiddle this works fine, as soon as I change the image source to my variable it becomes misplaced.
Any ideas why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't actually show the effect; but it is something you will always get in some way or other if the floated elements are not _exactly_ the same height. Your best bet is to not use floating at all, but either inline-block or flexbox.

Comment: <p style="clear: both;"></p>    get that out of the <ul>, that's invalid code. It's too hard to debug code when it's wrong technically. the only thing in a <ul> is a <li>. Post the entire bit of code, high odds there is another html error in there.

Comment: Fiddle shows how it should look like.

Comment: I agree re inline block vs float, but you have to also be aware that msie didn't support that until quite recently. Also, put a background color on your <li> to see what's actually going on there for debugging.

Comment: I listened to Cbroe and noticed that the img that was escaping has a height of 200.1px while all others where 200px. I set max-height to 200px and this fixed the issue.

Comment: If you set explicit img heights on these elements you won't have issues like this, easy.

Comment: Cheers Lizardx and Cbroe. I will keep this in mind next time.